# How to dynamically add marker to google maps component on HTTPGET (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, google-maps

I am building an Angular 6 application with a Google Javascript API integration using [AGM](https://angular-maps.com/). The map works except for adding markers dynamically using http get.

This is the `component.html`:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="51.017467" [longitude]="10.233982">
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let position of positions" [latitude]="position.latitude"
                [longitude]="position.longitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

And `component.ts`:

```
export class EventsListComponent {
 public positions = [new Position(51.017467, 10.233982)]; // static point for debug

 constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  let eventIds: string[] = ['5bffbac5596a7de59190dfbb']; // also for debug
  for (let eventId of eventIds) {
    this.http.get<Address>("api/v1/Events/Get/" + eventId +"/GetVenue/GetAddress").subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.addresses.push(result);
    });
  }
}

export class Address {

  constructor(
    public latitude: number,
    public longitude: number,
    public addressLine: string,
    public city: string,
    public state: string,
    public country: string,
    public zip) {
  }
}
```

This is printed to the console:

```
{
"addressLine":"Gartenstraße 7",
"city":"Eschwege",
"country":"Germany",
"zip":"37269",
"state":"Hessen",
"latitude":"51.1821073",
"longitude":"10.0572713"
}
```

**Produces the following result:**

[image: Adding marker with REST]

The marker shows up in the DOM but not on the map (The marker you see is the static one, there should be two).

### Something else I tried:

Adding markers dynamically works with button presses like this:

```
<button (click)="btnClick()" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
```

And then in the `component.ts`:

```
btnClick() {
    this.addresses.push(new Address(51.1821073, 10.0572713,"","","","",""));
}
```

**Produces the following result:**

[image: Adding marker with button]

The marker shows up in the DOM **and** on the map.

### Something else I tried (pt2):

Putting the http get request in the method called by the button press like this:

```
btnClick() {
    this.http.get<Address>("api/v1/Events/Get/" + eventId +"/GetVenue/GetAddress").subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    this.addresses.push(result);
  });
}
```

It still only adds the marker to the dom and not the map.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are passing the lat/lng as a string (as denoted by the `""` in your console log) when you are using the service call but you are passing it in as a number when you manually add it. Try doing something like this

```
this.addresses.push({
  addressLine: result.addressLine,
  city: result.city,
  country: result.country,
  zip: result.zip,
  state: result.state,
  latitude: +result.latitude,
  longitude: +result.longitude
});
```

or you could try shortening it up to something like this

```
result.latitude = +result.latitude;
result.longitude = +result.longitude;
this.addresses.push(result);
```

Comment: Hahaha I had been working on this for like 5 hours and just solved it not 2 mins before you posted this. I realised the problem when I printed out the static point next to the one from the get request and saw the different data types. It all works now :)

Comment: The interesting part, coming from a c#/java (strongly typed) background, is that in the Address class, both latitude and longitude are both of type number. Which means they should also be a number when referenced in the html file...

Comment: glad to hear you figured it out